# link_to is not working with a variable url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, link-to

I have a view that uses link_to to pass parameters to a controller. The url is a variable. Something is not working. I'd appreciate any clues. Thanks!

```
<% url1 = dialogs_path(@dialogId) %>
<%= url1 %>
<%= link_to "Go!", url1(:uid1 => @uid1, :uid2 => @uid2), :id => "my_link" %>
```

url1 displays correctly. However, executing link_to crashes.

Comment: What does "crashes" mean?  Seeing a stack trace or error message of some sort would help.

Comment: Thanks @BaronVonBraun! I'm working on it. When the page that includes the link_to statement is rendered I get "we are sorry, but something went wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `dialog_path(@dialogId)` instead.

You're trying to view a particular object, it's singular and what rails expects.
Take a look here :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

The way you use url confuses me, try something like this :

```
<%= link_to "Go!", dialog_path(@dialogId, :uid1 => @uid1, :uid2 => @uid2), :id => "my_link" %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony for your help!I corrected that. I also noticed that I had a typo "url" instead of "url1" and I corrected that but that did not work either. I'm still debugging.  Thanks again!

Comment: Edited, try the syntax in my answer

Comment: I did use dialog_path(@dialogId) instead. Thanks @Anthony!

Comment: Thanks! @Anthony, the fix that you suggested is not working for some reason. I'm using my less eloquent work-around.

Answer (score 0):

The url1 should be defined as:

```
<% url1 = dialogs_path(@dialogId)+'?uid1=' + @uid1 + '&uid2=' + @uid2% , :id => "my_link" %>
```

And the link_to should be:

```
<%= link_to "Go!", url1, :id => "my_link" %>
```

Comment: Pretty hacky way to do it, you're supposed to be able to add extra params using the `dialog_path` helper

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyAlberto for your help! But what would you suggest?

Comment: `dialog_path(@dialogId, :uid1 => @uid1, :uid2 => @uid2)` . If it doesn;t work, give the error you're getting, or the wrong link

Comment: It doesn't work. I'll go back and look into it. Thanks @AnthonyAlberto for your help!